# issue with sum of values for similar keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I have the following array

```
[["a", " 3"], ["a", " 5"], ["b", " 5"], ["c", " 2"], ["a", " 5"], ["a", " 5"], [
"b", " 4"], ["c", " 1"], ["c", " 2"], ["d", " 3"]]
```

I am looking to get the following output

```
[["a", "18"], ["b", "9"], ["c", " 5"], ["d", "3"]]
```

18 for key 'a' and the sum of all values 3+5+5+5

I have the following code

```
ary.group_by{|a, b| a}
```

and I am getting the following output

```
{"a"=>[["a", " 3"], ["a", " 5"], ["a", " 5"], ["a", " 5"]], "b"=>[["b", " 5"], [
"b", " 4"]], "c"=>[["c", " 2"], ["c", " 1"], ["c", " 2"], ["c", " 3"]]}
```

I tried doing the merge after grouping them by the keys and then sum the values after the merge, but I am getting an error! Could you point me in the right direction..

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a functional approach:

```
pairs.group_by(&:first).map do |key, groups|
  [key, groups.map { |k, v| v.to_i }.reduce(:+)]
end 
#=> [["a", 18], ["b", 9], ["c", 5], ["d", 3]]
```

Using [Facets](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#map_by-instance_method):

```
require 'facets'
pairs.map_by { |k, v| [k, v.to_i] }.map { |k, vs| [k, vs.reduce(:+)] }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
A = [["a", " 3"], ["a", " 5"], ["b", " 5"],
     ["c", " 2"], ["a", " 5"], ["a", " 5"],
     ["b", " 4"], ["c", " 1"], ["c", " 2"],
     ["d", " 3"]]

hash = A.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |acc, (k, v)|
  acc[k] += v.to_i
  acc
end

array = hash.map { |k, v| [k, v.to_s] }

p array

# => [["a", "18"], ["b", "9"], ["c", "5"], ["d", "3"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grouped = ary.group_by{|a, b| a}
result = grouped.map do |key, value|
  sum_over_arrays = value.map do |sub_arr|
    sub_arr.last.to_i # get only the second element and transform it in integer
  end.inject(:+) # sum over the resulting array of integer
  [key, sum_over_arrays] # return the new mapping [key, sum]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess at this :

```
ary.inject({}) { |init, (k,v)| init[k] = init[k].to_i + v.to_i; init }.to_a
```

You get `[["a", 18], ["b", 9], ["c", 5], ["d", 3]]`

Values are integers, but you can convert them back to strings if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [["a", " 3"], ["a", " 5"], ["b", " 5"], ["c", " 2"], ["a", " 5"], 
         ["a", " 5"], ["b", " 4"], ["c", " 1"], ["c", " 2"], ["d", " 3"]]

array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |ar,hash|
  hash[ar.first] += ar.last.to_i
end.map { |k,v| [k, v.to_s] }

#=> [["a", "18"], ["b", "9"], ["c", "5"], ["d", "3"]]
```